# In apps script, how do I parse dataSheet.appendRow, when one of the fields on my form is a checkbox containing an array?

Tags: javascript

I created a form and added a script to populate a Google sheet following this site...
https://codewithcurt.com/google-form-using-apps-script-to-populate-google-sheet/

It works as long as my form does not include a checkbox question item. If I make a checkbox item on the form, the sheet gets the response "[Ljava.lang.Object;@40637acb" instead of the expected output of "Monday, Wednesday".

I've been searching for days and I believe that it is because a checkbox item is an array and the "dataSheet.appendRow" function is sending the data as an array.

`    function onFormSubmit(event) {

```
  record_array = []

  const id = 'Form ID';    // Form ID
  const sid = 'Sheet ID';   // Sheet ID

  var form = FormApp.openById(id); // Form ID
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formCount = formResponses.length;

  var formResponse = formResponses[formCount - 1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
  var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();

    Logger.log(title);
    Logger.log(answer);

    record_array.push(answer);
  }

  AddRecord(record_array[0], record_array[1], record_array[2], record_array[3]);

}

function AddRecord(first_name, last_name, color,test) {
  var url = 'sheet url';   //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  dataSheet.appendRow([first_name, last_name, color, test, new Date()]);

}
```

`

I tried adding another variable under var answer (var checkanswer = itemResponse.getResponse();)

I Googled searching for some sample of code, but I didn't find anything matching what I needed. I changed the form from checkboxes to radio buttons and it works, but I can only choose one option.

Sample Google Form for Tanaike:
[Sample Google Form for Tanaike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYkRH.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your script and your situation `If I make a checkbox item on the form, the sheet gets the response "[Ljava.lang.Object;@40637acb" instead of the expected output of "Monday, Wednesday".`, I thought that an array might be included in `record_array`. When an array is put using `appendRow`, such value is used. In order to avoid this, how about the following modification?

Please modify your showing script as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
record_array.push(answer);
```

#### To:

```
record_array.push(Array.isArray(answer) ? answer.join(",") : answer);
```

- By this, when the value of `answer` is an array, it is converted to a string value using `join`.

Comment: I made the suggested change and the checkbox data now comes across correctly, but the other data is blank.

google sheet shows:  |    |     |    |Thursday evening| (the first three columns are now blank. I'm guessing that it's because they are not arrays but normal data.)

I will take the direction that you gave and research some more to see if I can figure out the issue. Thank you for your tip, it was just what I was looking for.

Comment: I used your suggestion and it led me to find the flat command, which flattens out arrays inside other arrays. flat doesn't seem to work in apps script.

that led me to find reduce. but that too didn't seem to work in apps script.

that led me to concat, which seemed to work, but I had to just keep messing with it until I figured out the right place to put it.

forgive me if the terminology is all wrong. I've never coded a day in my life.

Comment: let flattened = [].concat.apply([], AddRecord(record_array[0], record_array[1], record_array[2], record_array[3]));
// Expected DATA  Joe Dirt, joe@dirt.com, Phone number, 9897991212, [Tuesday evening, Thursday evening, Saturday morning]
}
function AddRecord(first_name, last_name, color, test) {
  var url = 'url';   //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WBS");
  let flattened = [].concat.apply([], [first_name, last_name, color, test, new Date()]);
  Logger.log(flattened);
  dataSheet.appendRow(flattened);
}

Comment: I'm not sure how to give you points or whatever. I tried to uptick your answer but it wouldnt let me.

Comment: @Joe Hobarth Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, it is required to correctly replicate your situation. So, can you provide your sample Google Form? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: This site is so frustrating. I can't add (@Tanaike ) to my comment. 

I added my Google Form to the original question (I couldn't add it to a comment). Please let me know if that is the wrong place to add it. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Joe Hobarth Thank you for replying. I created a Google Form using your provided image and tested it using my proposed modification. All values are put into "Sheet1". Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `but the other data is blank. google sheet shows`. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating `but the other data is blank. google sheet shows`? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?